# Prometheus push gateway only returns the last value instead of all

Tags: reactjs, prometheus, prometheus-pushgateway

I use the push gateway from prometheus (https://prometheus.io/docs/practices/pushing/).
And I push some metrics from a React UI very often like this:

```
# HELP prom_react_app_availability_total Application availability counter
# TYPE prom_react_app_availability_total counter
prom_react_app_availability_total{owner="test", status="started", timestamp="2022-09-13T06:48:19.280Z"} 1
```

and sometimes I have a "failed" status after "started".

```
# HELP prom_react_app_availability_total Application availability counter
# TYPE prom_react_app_availability_total counter
prom_react_app_availability_total{owner="test", status="failed", timestamp="2022-09-13T06:52:19.280Z"} 1
```

But when I take a look on the gateway's /metrics endpoint, then I only see the last value instead of all the submitted values over time.
My Prometheus server collects data from this endpoint every 30s and so I lost a lot of data and maybe also the "failed", that occurred because the next push was a status="started".
I thought, I see all events or a summary with increased values.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Prometheus Pushgateway](https://github.com/prometheus/pushgateway) remembers only the last pushed sample per each time series by design. See [these docs](https://github.com/prometheus/pushgateway#non-goals). If you want counting events when your app was available/unavailable, then take a look at [statsd_exporter](https://github.com/prometheus/statsd_exporter).

Side suggestion: it isn't recommended storing timestamps in metric labels, since every unique timestamp results in a new time series. This may slow down Prometheus  and increase its memory usage significantly. Such a condition is named [high churn rate](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/FAQ.html#what-is-high-churn-rate) and/or [high cardinality](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/FAQ.html#what-is-high-cardinality). See also [these docs](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/keyConcepts.html#what-is-a-metric).